# The object is reaching resolve object

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
// This is ionic code
.state('tab.chat-details', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'chat-details': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailController',
          resolve: {
            chat: ['$stateParams', 'Chats', function($stateParams,Chats) {
              var ran = Chats.getChat(parseInt($stateParams.chatId, 10));
              console.log(ran);
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    })

// service code

getChat: function(chatId) {
      chats.forEach(function(value, key) {
        if(value.id === chatId) {
          return value;
        }
      })
    }
```

//context
    When I opened my debugger the proper value is getting returned but finally when it reached my resolve object it is showing undefined. Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your chat property function is not returning anything.

I do not know much about Ionic, but I'm guessing that its resolve property is the same as Angular's $routeProvider one which is `resolve - {Object.<string, function>=}`.

Each property in the resolve object is a function.  The controller will load with the injected dependencies after all of your resolve functions have returned values (or if those return values were promises, after those have all been resolved).

You should be able to resolve this by simply returning your "ran" object.

```
// This is ionic code
.state('tab.chat-details', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'chat-details': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailController',
          resolve: {
            chat: ['$stateParams', 'Chats', function($stateParams,Chats) {
              var ran = Chats.getChat(parseInt($stateParams.chatId, 10));
              console.log(ran);
              return ran;
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    })
```